# How to use Connection Pooling with Hazelcast jet JDBC?

Tags: java, java-8, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am trying to use connection pooling with hazelcast jet jdbc but it is not allowing me to do it.
I have Datasource bean from which I am fetching connection but it is not working.
Here is my code:

```
Connection conn = ((DataSource)Ds.getBean("dataSourceName").getConnection();
BatchSource<Object> jdbcSource = Sources
                .jdbc(() -> conn,
                    (con, parallelism, index) -> {
                       // query execution
               }, r -> this.mapResultSet1(r, metaData));
```

But when I execute it gives me below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "newConnectionFn" must be serializable
at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.checkSerializable(Util.java:203)
at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.connector.ReadJdbcP.supplier(ReadJdbcP.java:77)
at com.hazelcast.jet.core.processor.SourceProcessors.readJdbcP(SourceProcessors.java:433)
at com.hazelcast.jet.pipeline.Sources.jdbc(Sources.java:1327)
at com.aivdata.impl.JDBCDataSource.readSource(JDBCDataSource.java:70)
at com.aivdata.services.AivDataFactory.lambda$1(AivDataFactory.java:123)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.checkSerializable(Util.java:201)
```

How can I achieve this how to use connection pooling with Hazelcast jet?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me if I take connection inside Source Jdbc but not sure if it is using Pooling or creating new one.

```
BatchSource<Object> jdbcSource = Sources
                .jdbc(() -> {
                      Connection conn = ((DataSource)Ds.getBean("dataSourceName").getConnection();
                      return conn;
                  },
                    (con, parallelism, index) -> {
                       // query execution
               }, r -> this.mapResultSet1(r, metaData));
```

Comment: Yes, if the `Ds.getBean` returns the same instance every time you call it then this is more or less what meant by "make connection pool instance available from the serializable newConnectionFn function"

Comment: @FrantišekHartman thank you for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you that the following function is not serializable:

```
() -> conn
```

Instead, you should use something similar to:

```
() -> DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectionUrl)
```

The JDBC source uses the provided function to create a connection for each processor instance - this means that on each cluster member it will create `n` connections where `n` is equal to the local parallelism of the JDBC source. The default value for local parallelism is 1. You can modify this value by calling `com.hazelcast.jet.pipeline.BatchStage#setLocalParallelism` on the JDBC source.

If your job is a one-time batch job or a long-running batch job then it doesn't make sense to use a connection pool.

It might make sense to use a connection pool if you execute many small instances of a job, where creating a connection for each job execution would cause too much overhead. In that case you need to make your connection pool instance available from the serializable `newConnectionFn` function, e.g. by making it a singleton in a static field, initialized lazily.

Comment: I have spring boot application and their can be multiple request at time for that I need connection pooling I cannot create a new connection on each request.  Ans sorry I didn't get this point  "In that case you need to make your connection pool instance available from the serializable newConnectionFn function, e.g. by making it a singleton in a static field, initialized lazily."